# jquery change url location

Tags: jquery, css

I need to change the url location on click then update the css of    .accordionContent`

- the url change takes effect but any code after fails to work.

Here's my current code
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[data-acc='1']").click(function(){
    var url = "mysite.com";
    $(location).attr('href',url);
    $('.accordionContent').css("display", "block"); 
    });
    });

Can anyone explain the best way to achieve this?
thanks, code below:

Comment: You haven't set the variable `location` being used here `$(location).attr('href',url);`

Comment: It makes no sense to go to another site, and then try and execute any other JS code after that. Even if the browser does still execute it, it will do so on the page the user was on, its effect will be lost when the browser loads the new page.

Comment: how can I achieve this? I basically need to click on a link and go to a page with an accordian and change the display value of a class via css. Thank you

Comment: Have the link take them to the other page and have that page handle any changes.

Comment: Do you mean you redirect to the page once you click this `$("a[data-acc='1']")` ?   Or you just want to update a certain link ? Knowing what's inside this `location` from here `$(location).attr('href',url);` will definitely clear some questions.

Comment: The code might be working but then you are leaving the page

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `location.href` like that will cause the page to reload, like @CBroe says. You can use javascript's [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) to update this browser's URL dynamically.

Try:

```
history.pushState(null, title, url);
$('.accordionContent').css("display", "block");
```